# need to create a new column in existing table and split the data from 1 column to new column

Tags: sql-server

I'm using MS SQL Server.

I have data in one column called `first name` in the format `ANNETTE W * LOW`

I want to create another column called `last name` and put all the data from the `first name` column that comes after the `*` into this new column.

#### Input

```
first name
---------------
ANNETTE W * LOW
```

#### Desired Output

```
first name | last name
-----------+----------
ANNETTE W  | LOW
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` to do this

- `charIndex('*',firstName)` - it gives you the position of character `*` inside firstName. In this case  `charIndex('*',firstName) =  11`.
- `substring(firstName,1,charIndex('*',firstName) -1)` - is extracting a portion of string from firstName from starting position = 1 till/length charIndex('*',firstName) -1 = 11- 1 = 10
- `substring(firstName
          , charIndex('*',firstName) + 1 
         ,len(firstName) - (charIndex('*',firstName)))` - extracting a string from firstName where the starting point `charIndex('*',firstName) + 1`  = 11+ 1 =12 and `len(firstName) - (charIndex('*',firstName)))` = 15  - 11 = 4
- because there is a space character in expression `LOW`, you need to add `LTRIM` = to get rid of this.

### code

```
create table Source
 (firstName varchar(50))    
insert into Source(firstName)
values('ANNETTE W * LOW')

select 
    substring(firstName,1,charIndex('*',firstName) -1) as  firstName
    , ltrim(substring(firstName, charIndex('*',firstName) + 1
            ,len(firstName) - (charIndex('*',firstName)))) as lastName
    ,charIndex('*',firstName) as positionChar
    ,len(firstName) as lengthString
from Source as S
```

output:

```
firstName   lastName    positionChar    lengthString
ANNETTE W   LOW         11               15
```

#### #

```
ALTER TABLE Source
   ADD lastName varchar(50) null

UPDATE Source
  SET lastName = ltrim(substring(firstName, charIndex('*',firstName) + 1
                      ,len(firstName) - (charIndex('*',firstName))))
       ,firstName = substring(firstName,1,charIndex('*',firstName) -1)

SELECT * FROM Source
```

output

```
firstName   lastName
ANNETTE W   LOW
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0dde9c70c3ae04e8ab3021c3d17033aa)

Answer (score -1):

You below code.

```
SELECT   
SUBSTRING(Firstname,1,CHARINDEX('*',Firstname)-1) AS FName
, SUBSTRING(Firstname,CHARINDEX('*',Firstname)+1,LEN(Firstname)) AS LName
FROM Tablename T
```